# force hyperjaxb2 to generate a fetch="select" propertie on hibernate mapping (on <join> tag)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hyperjaxb

We have found a problem on our application (a select query that join too much tables). The solution of this problem is to set `fetch="select"` on the `<join>` tag in our hibernate mapping file.

```
<subclass extends="...">
   <join table="MyTable" fetch="select">
   ...
   </join>
</subclass>
```

But this mapping is generated by hyberjaxb2. I haven't found how to add the fetch attribute into the `<join>` tag. I can change the target table name (ie: MyTable) using this :

```
<hj:table name="MyTable"/>
```

but if I change it to

```
<hj:table name="MyTable" fetch="select" />
```

nothing is added in my mapping file.

So, how can I add the fetch propertie on the `<join>` tag using hyperjaxb2 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken from hyperjaxb2 reference documentation : 
https://hyperjaxb2.dev.java.net/nonav/hyperjaxb2/reference/reference.html#d0e850

> In case you XML Schema construct maps onto a table, you can customize table name, schema or catalog
>   with a table customization element.

So I can't add my fetch attribut...